# Connection with Mogodb

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, docker

Good morning. I have a problem connecting to a MongoDB database. I have configured myself a database and mongo express in docker-compose.yml file. Using CommandLineRunner, I want to add sample data to the database and then the connection is rejected.

Main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MongoDbApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MongoDbApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner run(StudentRepository studentRepository) {
        return args -> {
            Address address = new Address("Poland", "00-000", "Warszawa");
            Student student = new Student("Grzegorz", "Grzegorzewski", "grzegorz.grzegorzewski@gmail.com",
                    Gender.MALE, address, List.of("Street workout"), BigDecimal.TEN, LocalDateTime.now());
            studentRepository.insert(student);
        };
    }
}
```

Document class

```
@Data
@Document
public class Student {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String email;
    private Gender gender;
    private Address address;
    private List<String> favouriteSubjects;
    private BigDecimal totalSpentInBooks;
    private LocalDateTime created;

    public Student(String firstname, String lastname, String email, Gender gender, Address address,
                   List<String> favouriteSubjects, BigDecimal totalSpentInBooks, LocalDateTime created) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.email = email;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.address = address;
        this.favouriteSubjects = favouriteSubjects;
        this.totalSpentInBooks = totalSpentInBooks;
        this.created = created;
    }
}
```

application.properties file

```
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=admin
spring.data.mongodb.username=rootuser
spring.data.mongodb.password=rootpass
spring.data.mongodb.database=amigoscode
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
```

MongoRepository

```
@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends MongoRepository<Student, String> {
}
```

docker-compose file

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongodb
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - data:/data
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=rootuser
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpass
  mongo-expres:
    image: mongo-express
    container_name: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=rootuser
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=rootpass
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb
volumes:
  data: { }
networks:
  default:
    name: mongodb_network
```

Error stack trace

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-07-27 07:58:41.235 ERROR 940 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:774) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:755) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at com.example.MongoDB.MongoDbApplication.main(MongoDbApplication.java:16) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='rootuser', source='admin', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='rootuser', source='admin', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MongoExceptionTranslator.java:140) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(MongoTemplate.java:3044) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:600) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.insertDocument(MongoTemplate.java:1546) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doInsert(MongoTemplate.java:1345) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.insert(MongoTemplate.java:1260) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.insert(SimpleMongoRepository.java:286) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:530) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:286) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:640) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:164) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:81) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy56.insert(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy56.insert(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.example.MongoDB.MongoDbApplication.lambda$run$0(MongoDbApplication.java:25) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:771) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='rootuser', source='admin', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.wrapException(SaslAuthenticator.java:276) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.getNextSaslResponse(SaslAuthenticator.java:139) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.access$100(SaslAuthenticator.java:49) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator$1.run(SaslAuthenticator.java:65) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator$1.run(SaslAuthenticator.java:59) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.doAsSubject(SaslAuthenticator.java:283) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.authenticate(SaslAuthenticator.java:59) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultAuthenticator.authenticate(DefaultAuthenticator.java:57) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.authenticate(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:207) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.finishHandshake(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:81) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:185) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection.open(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:54) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection.open(DefaultConnectionPool.java:535) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$OpenConcurrencyLimiter.openWithConcurrencyLimit(DefaultConnectionPool.java:911) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$OpenConcurrencyLimiter.openOrGetAvailable(DefaultConnectionPool.java:852) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool.get(DefaultConnectionPool.java:178) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool.get(DefaultConnectionPool.java:167) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServer.getConnection(DefaultServer.java:103) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.binding.ClusterBinding$ClusterBindingConnectionSource.getConnection(ClusterBinding.java:175) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.ClientSessionBinding$SessionBindingConnectionSource.getConnection(ClientSessionBinding.java:192) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.OperationHelper.withSuppliedResource(OperationHelper.java:592) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.OperationHelper.lambda$withSourceAndConnection$3(OperationHelper.java:574) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.OperationHelper.withSuppliedResource(OperationHelper.java:600) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.OperationHelper.withSourceAndConnection(OperationHelper.java:573) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.lambda$execute$3(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:272) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.async.function.RetryingSyncSupplier.get(RetryingSyncSupplier.java:65) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.execute(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:308) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.execute(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:85) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.execute(MongoClientDelegate.java:212) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.executeSingleWriteRequest(MongoCollectionImpl.java:1010) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.executeInsertOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:471) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.insertOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:454) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.insertOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:448) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.lambda$insertDocument$15(MongoTemplate.java:1552) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:598) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 18 (AuthenticationFailed): 'Authentication failed.' on server localhost:27017. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "Authentication failed.", "code": 18, "codeName": "AuthenticationFailed"}
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.ProtocolHelper.getCommandFailureException(ProtocolHelper.java:198) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:413) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:337) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:101) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:45) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.sendSaslStart(SaslAuthenticator.java:230) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.getNextSaslResponse(SaslAuthenticator.java:137) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    ... 71 common frames omitted
```

I have no more ideas about what I can still change here. I will be very grateful for any tips. Thank you all in advance for your hints.

Answer (score 0):

If you define a network in the compose file, you should connect the containers to it.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#specify-custom-networks

Comment: He reconfigured the default network so no need to make each service join it

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have read the documentation and there is no answer to my problem there. 
Just to mention that I wrote this simple application on a MacBook Air with m1 processor. I tried exactly the same way to run the application on a computer with an Intel processor, and there the first time everything ran without a problem. Maybe the problem is that it has a computer with an m1 processor ?